# How to delete a substring using shell script

Tags: shell, substring

I have strings called:

```
abc.out
def.out
```

How do I delete the substring

> .out

In these strings?

What command should I use?
(Bourne Shell)

Answer (score 53):

Multiple ways, a selection:

`str=abc.out`

**Shell:**

```
echo ${str%.*}
```

**Grep:**

```
echo $str | grep -o '^[^\.]*'
```

**Sed:**

```
echo $str | sed -E 's/(.*?)\..*/\1/'
```

**Awk:**

```
echo $str | awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

`-F.` means split the string by . and `$1` means the first column.

**Cut:**

`echo $str | cut -d. -f1`

**All output:**

```
abc
```

Answer (score 31):

I found this worked best because the pattern you want to use can be in a variable:

```
DATA="abc.out"
pattern=".out"
DATA=${DATA/$pattern/}
echo "DATA=${DATA}"
```

The result is:

`abc`

Comment: Works for prefixes as well :) Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

**If these strings are stored in a file** (let's call it `input_file`):

```
# input_file:

abc.out abc.out abc.out
def.out def.out
def.out
```

You can do:

```
sed -i 's/\.out//g' input_file
```

And this will remove any occurrence of the substring `.out` from that file.

**Explanation:**

- `sed`: invoke the [sed](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) tool to edit streams of text
- `-i`: use the "in-place" option - this modifies the input file you provide it instead of writing output to `stdout`
- `'s/\.out//g'`: Use regular expression to delete `.out`. the `g` at the end means delete all occurrences.
- `input_file`: specify the input file

---

**If these strings are stored in variables:**

```
var1="abc.out"
```

You can use [parameter subsitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

```
var1=${var1%.out}
echo "$var1"

abc
```

**Explanation:**

- From the above link: *"${var%Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the back end of $var."*
- Note that the "pattern" mentioned here is called globbing, which is [different from regular expression in important ways](http://lwn.net/Articles/96687/).

Comment: You need an end of line anchor on your sed versions, and the `g` flag is probably undesirable.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I guess that depends on exact input of his files: you are right, I should make my assumptions more clear.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ foo=abc.def.out
$ echo ${foo%.out}
abc.def
```

In general, to delete the shortest suffix, use:

```
$ echo ${foo%.*}
abc.def
```

To delete the longest suffix, use

```
$ echo ${foo%%.*}
abc
```

Comment: Removes only suffixes, not substrings as was asked for.

Comment: @not2savvy The OP used the word "substring", but is clearly asking only to delete suffixes.  Shall we take all questions literally?  I estimate that at least 85% of all questions asked are stated incorrectly.  If answered literally, the answers would all be useless.

Comment: I think he’s not „clearly asking only to delete suffixes“, bzt he just gave that as one example of what he’s asking for. Perhaps I’m wrong. However, an answer that gives a more general approach is obviously useful for more people. Just saying!

Answer (score 1):

If these are filenames, you can use basename.

```
$ basename a.out .out
```

will give you:

```
a
```

Comment: `basename -s .out a.out` works too if you like writing your options.

Answer (score 0):

An example in `zsh`:

```
% myVar="abc.out def.out ghi.out"

% myVar=${myVar:s/.out/} # replace first match of ".out" with ""
% echo myVar
abc def.out ghi.out

% myVar=${myVar:gs/.out/} # replace all matches of ".out" with ""
% echo myVar
abc def ghi
```